# How to reverse cellphone firmware

Tags: reverse-engineering, firmware

I want to get full list of supported AT commands and other undocumented codes for some cell phone. I found that using `strings` command (on linux or win alternative) I can get all ASCII or UTF constant strings from firmware binary file, but it is a junk.
I don't have any JTAG hardware.
Maybe I should get fullflash from the device and look for some interrup routines.

Is there any other way to get these info?

Comment: What phone firmware do you have that's not encrypted?  I suspect that the firmware binary file you have is actually an encrypted block to be decrypted and written by the bootloader on the phone.

Answer (score 6):

In order to get a list of all supported AT commands, you can just run `AT+CLAC` which will list just that. It is a [standardized command](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) which, although optional, I assume virtuall all manufacturers support. Sony-Ericsson phones (as well as other phones based on platforms from [Ericsson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ericsson_Mobile_Platforms)/ST-Ericsson) also support `AT*` as an alternative command (with an optional numeric parameter for different output formatting (e.g. `AT*2`)).